# How to make a parachain project that uses Frontier as a dependency?

Tags: parachain, frontier, frontier-node-template, substrate-parachain-template, frontier-workshop

I have a parachain project that uses Frontier as a dependency with a specific Substrate version(polkadot-v0.9.24), but the Ethereum RPC does not work. So I need to find the bug there...

Also I am aware of @JoshOrndorff's tutorial https://github.com/PureStake/substrate-node-template/commits/frontier-workshop-2021
about how to add Frontier into a Substrate Node Template: https://github.com/PureStake/substrate-node-template/commits/frontier-workshop-2021, but that is a few months old with different substrate version...

And the above is how to add Frontier as a dependency to Substrate Node Template,

but how to add Frontier as a dependency to Substrate Parachain Template?

Regarding the Frontier repo template...
quote from Frontier https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/tree/master/template: "used to generate a stand-alone template for use in an independent project via the included [template generation script](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/master/docs/node-template-release.md)."

Can this template generate a parachain project(based on substrate parachain template)?

I need to generate a parachain project(based on substrate parachain template) that uses Frontier repo as a dependency.
How can I do that?

I found out some Frontier templates have been built and uploaded into Frontier Node Template repo https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/tree/main

It seems I can just copy the files under that repo above/node and runtime folder, then make my parachain from there. Is that a quick way to make my template parachain?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Frontier Node Template repo https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template

Copy the files in node and runtime folders inside the above repo, then make your parachain from there. It is the quickest way to make a parachain that uses Frontier as a dependency.

Also check out other open source parachain repositories for specific Substrate versions!

See part 2 of this question: [How to add Frontier code as a dependency to substrate-parachain-template based parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4227/how-to-add-frontier-code-as-a-dependency-to-substrate-parachain-template-based-p/4295#4295)