# How to add Frontier code as a dependency to substrate-parachain-template based parachain?

Tags: parachain, frontier

Hi I was trying to add Frontier code to my substrate-parachain-template project.

I was following JoshOrndorff's tutorial and his commits here https://github.com/PureStake/substrate-node-template/commits/frontier-workshop-2021

However, Josh's tutorial is a little outdated and his code is based on Substrate-Node-template instead of Substrate-Parachain-template...

So currently I am trying to add Frontier's template folder code into my Substrate-parachain-template repo. I think that is also the approach Josh was using, right?

After following that approach, almost all code can be added from Frontier/template to my parachain, except node/service.rs...  because it is surprisingly complicated!...

For example, I need to remove `sc_finality_grandpa` from the Frontier/template to make it work with any parachain. but I don't know what can be used to replace `sc_finality_grandpa::GrandpaBlockImport<FullBackend, Block, FullClient, FullSelectChain>,`?

```
pub type ConsensusResult = (
    FrontierBlockImport<
        Block,
        sc_finality_grandpa::GrandpaBlockImport<FullBackend, Block, FullClient, FullSelectChain>,
        FullClient,
    >,
    sc_finality_grandpa::LinkHalf<Block, FullClient, FullSelectChain>,
);
```

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1 of this question:
[How to make a parachain project that uses Frontier as a dependency?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3796/how-to-make-a-parachain-project-that-uses-frontier-as-a-dependency)

Merge Fronter repo/template folder into your parachain... although I am stuck at node/service.rs but it seems it is okay to skip those...

Regarding to ERC777 contracts, you have to

- use deploy the ERC1820 first ... see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17927/how-to-deploy-smart-contract-in-predefined-contract-address-in-private-ethereum/79316#79316
- use deploy ERC777 second ... see
  https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/simple-erc777-token-example/746

Both Hardhat or Truffle can deploy upgradeable and ERC777 contracts...
See `ExhaustsResources` error solution  [deploy solidity ethereum to parachain with ExhaustsResources error](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3882/deploy-solidity-ethereum-to-parachain-with-exhaustsresources-error/4322#4322)